# mvc core 2.0, how to use an appSettings.json file via configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0

Today I was trying out the new asp.net core 2.0 but ran into some trouble using a JSON configuration file that I wasnt to inject in  IConfiguration configuration constructor property.

In asp.net core 1.1 I would use this following code in StartUp:

```
public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration;

Public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env) {
     var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
     .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
     .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)

  Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

and could access it from the code like:

```
private string _mailTo = Startup.Configuration["mailSettings:mailToAddress"];
```

However In Core 2.0 they changed to IConfiguration and it's already defined moreover I don't see any way i can use the configuration in my other classes, so I'm kinda clueless on how to proceed.

The startupClass:

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;
using NLog.Web;
using NLog.Extensions.Logging;
using cityInfoTestApi.Services;

namespace cityInfoTestApi
{
    public class Startup
    {

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc()
                .AddMvcOptions(o => o.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter()));




        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddNLog();
            app.AddNLogWeb();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseStatusCodePages();
            app.UseMvc();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });


        }
    }
}
```

my json file:

```
{
    "mailSetings": {
        "mailToAddress": "admin@mycompany.com",
        "mailFromAddress":  "noreply@mycompany.com"
    }
}
```

my custom class wanting to use the settings (note it was how i would use core 1.1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace cityInfoTestApi.Services
{
    public class LocalMailService : IMailService
    {

        private string _mailTo = Startup.Configuration["mailSettings:mailToAddress"];
        private string _mailFrom = Startup.Configuration["mailSettings:mailFromAddress"];


        public void Send(string subject, string message)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Mail from {_mailFrom} to {_mailTo}, with LocalMailService");
            Debug.WriteLine($"Subject: {subject}");
            Debug.WriteLine($"Message: {message}");
        }
    }
}
```

any help would be much appreciated, Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, ASP.NET Core 2.0 has changed the way for configuration building. You need to use `IWebHostBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration` method now.

Add something like this to your `IWebHost` creation in Program.cs:

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
{
    IHostingEnvironment env = builderContext.HostingEnvironment;

    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
          .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
})
```

Then `IConfiguration` instance may be injected to your `Startup` class via constructor as a dependency (or any other class, thanks to DI mechanism):

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
       Configuration = configuration;
    }
    ...
 }
```

There is a good article that describes those changes: [ASP.NET Core 2.0 Configuration Changes](https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-2-configuration-changes)

---

Regarding your way to get access to settings from custom classes (like `LocalMailService`) - avoid using any static dependencies. This broken DI conception used in ASP.NET Core. Read about using [IOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?) feature instead. Or you may again use DI and get `IConfiguration` instance via ctor in `LocalMailService`.

Comment: The question is about how to *use* the configuration in the rest of the application. This does not answer that.

Comment: @NightOwl888 thanks, was not too careful, have updated post

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use IOptions to pass a configuration file to your service.
Create a class for your configuration:

```
public class MailSetings
{
    public string MailToAddress {get;set;}
    public string MailFromAddress {get;set}

    public class MailSetings() { }
}
```

Configure the service to use those settings:

```
//...
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
//...

public class Startup
{
    //..

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<MailSetings>(Configuration);
        //...
    }
```

Now you should be able to inject this in your service constructor:

```
//...
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

public class LocalMailService : IMailService
{
    private string _mailTo;
    private string _mailFrom;

    public LocalMailService(IOptions<MailSetings> options)
    {
        _mailTo = options.Value.MailToAddress;
        _mailFrom = options.Value.MailFromAddress;
    }

    //...
}
```