# Read appsettings.json from a class in .NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, appsettings

I need to read a list of properties from `appsettings.json` file (section: `placeto`) in a business class, but I haven't been able to access them. I need these properties to be public.

I add the file in the `Program` class:

[image: Class program]

This is my `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "placeto": {
    "login": "fsdfsdfsfddfdfdfdf",
    "trankey": "sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf"
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632090/mvc-core-2-0-how-to-use-an-appsettings-json-file-via-configuration/46632521#46632521

Comment: This documentation from MS explain it how to => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration

Comment: but i need read in custom class, the example is in  controllers and i haven tried  several options. in .Net standard used  ` string userName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PFUserName"];` for read web.config, in .Net core which is equivalent  @CodeNotFound

Comment: The answer I linked you shows how to use `appsettings.json` in a class. In that case is a `LocalMailService` but it could be anything you want it to be.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**First** : Use the default in `program.cs` for it already adds Configuration:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

**Second** : Create an Interface for your class and pass configuration with dependency injection by creating `Iconfiguration` field:

```
private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;
```

then pass it by contructor:

```
public Test(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}
```

Then create an interface for your class in order to use `Dependency Injection` properly. Then one can create instances of it without needing to pass `IConfiguration` to it.

Here is the class and Interface:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace GetUserIdAsyncNullExample
{
    public interface ITest { void Method(); }

    public class Test : ITest
    {
        public Test(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;
        public void Method()
        {
            string here = Configuration["placeto:login"];
        }
    }
}
```

**Third**: Then in your startup.cs implement Dependency Injection for your class by calling:

```
services.AddSingleton< ITest, Test>();
```

in your `ConfigureServices` method

Now you can pass your class instances to any class used by Dependency Injection too.

---

For example, if you have `ExampleController` that you wanna use your class within do the following:

```
 private readonly ITest _test;

 public ExampleController(ITest test) 
 {
     _test = test;          
 }
```

And now you have _test instance to access it anywhere in your controller.