# Reading configuration value in a constant class in .Net Core 2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, configuration, asp.net-core-2.0

I have created a appsettings.json file to store all constant information.

I am creating a .Net Core 2 console application, and need to access this through a global constant file.

What ever online resources I am seeing basically says how to access it in program.cs file only.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "constant class". In any case, you cannot use `const` since that's at build-time and you want run-time values. If you refer to a `static` class with `static` variables, it's the same as any class so your question isn't clear

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto , basically I want to declare it once, and want to use it everywhere in the codebase, with out much repetitive code.

Answer (score 0):

The appsettings.json Configuration can be inserted at any class using `Dependency Injection`

```
public class Test 
{
    public Test(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;
```

Comment: If you have already answered the question, you need to flag this as a duplicate of that question, not post another answer which is a bad copy-paste. Please delete this

Comment: How would you call this class from another class? e.g. Test x = new Test();   (it wants me to put in the value for the IConfiguration configuration but I don't have it as it is injected via DI?

Comment: by DI see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47420522/read-appsettings-json-from-a-class-in-net-core-2/48728973#48728973