# .Net core 2 web api not injecting configuration into service

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

For some reason that I can't pin down, DI is not working with configuration in my .Net core 2 web api. Here's the code:

Program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMyService service;

    public MyController(IMyService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(service.MyMethod());
    }
}
```

My service:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration config;

    public MyService(IConfiguration config)
    {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public string MyMethod()
    {
        var test = config["MySetting"]; // <-- Breaks here. config is null.
    }
}
```

I've read through the configuration docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?tabs=basicconfiguration) and through SO posts [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47420522/read-appsettings-json-from-a-class-in-net-core-2) and cannot seem to figure out why DI is not working for me. Any thoughts? Something I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: I apologize, I misread your initial configuration when I posted my answer. What does your controller and constructor look like where you're calling `MyMethod()`?

Comment: No worries, I appreciate you taking time to help me. I updated my post with the controller code.

Comment: What you mean by _not working_? What exception have been thrown if so?

Comment: Seems like you need register `IConfiguration` for services too: `services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);`

Comment: @Fabio, null pointer exception. See my comment in the MyService.cs code snippet.

Comment: @Fabio, that didn't work :( I went with the options pattern as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options) and that worked for me.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce your exact setup and it is working fine for me (as expected). Are you sure that you didn’t leave something out? Can you try debugging the application and check whether the `IConfiguration` object is non-null within the Startup and in the constructor of `MyService`?

Answer (score 3):

This has been working well for me.

If you need "MySettings" section added to DI, create your configuration model class *MySettingsConfiguration* and add this to Startup.cs

```
services.Configure<MySettingsConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("MySettings"));
```

This can be later used in your constructor, either with scoped service via

```
public MyService(IOptionsSnapshot<MySettingsConfiguration> mySettingsConfiguration) { }
```

or with a singleton service

```
public MyService(IOptions<MySettingsConfiguration> mySettingsConfiguration) { }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to add a line to your ConfigureServices in your Startup.cs:

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
```

Here is a full example: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dariuszporowski/tip-of-the-week-how-to-access-configuration-from-controller-in-asp-net-core-2-0/

Comment: I actually tried that already, and it didn't work :( I went with the options pattern as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options) and that worked for me.

Comment: This is **not** necessary. In ASP.NET Core 2, configuration moved into DI with the WebHostBuilder, so the configuration object already is registered as a singleton. That is how the `Startup` class gets the configuration object, using DI.

Comment: THIS ACTUALLY WORKED!